# Proibir cadastro duplicado

Tags: java, primefaces, hibernate, postgresql, xhtml

Olá, pessoal. Estou com um programa que trabalha com cadastro de usuários. Neste programa eu gostaria de implementar uma função que proíba o cadastro de cpf ou email que já existe no banco de dados.

Como banco de dados eu estou usando o postgreSQL e o Hibernate do Java.
Para componentes visuais, estou usando o PrimeFaces.

Para desenvolvimento estou usando o Eclipse Mars .1

Para autenticação e autorização, estou usando o Spring Security.

Eu já pesquisei na internet e encontrei vários tópicos relacionados a este assunto e teve um onde o pessoal indicava para colocar a coluna cpf e email como "unique". Assim, o banco de dados não permite cadastrar dados duplicados.
Testei e funcionou, mas a questão é que o sistema devolve erro pelo console do Eclipse e simplesmente uma página de erro no navegador. Eu gostaria que simplesmente o sistema mostrasse alguma mensagem do tipo "este cpf já existe no sistema". Guiar o usuário para uma página cheia de códigos de erro seria bastante desagradável.

Estou postando os códigos dos arquivos que acredito que tenham alguma relação com o tratamento do campo CPF e email da tela de cadastro de usuário.

**CadastroUsuario.xhtml**

```
<ui:define name="titulo">#{cadastroUsuarioBean.editando ? "Editar Cadastro de Usuário" : "Novo Usuário"}</ui:define>

<ui:define name="corpo">
<f:metadata>
    <o:viewParam name="usuario" value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.usuario}"/>
    <f:event listener="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.inicializar}" type="preRenderView"/>
</f:metadata>


<h:form>
    <h1>#{cadastroUsuarioBean.editando ? "Editar Cadastro de Usuário" : "Novo Usuário"}</h1>

    <p:messages autoUpdate="true" closable="true"/>

    <p:toolbar style="margin-top: 20px">
        <p:toolbarGroup>
            <p:button value="Novo" outcome="/usuario/CadastroUsuario" disabled ="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.editando}"/>
            <p:commandButton value="Salvar" id="botaoSalvar" action="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.salvar}" update="@form" />
        </p:toolbarGroup>
        <p:toolbarGroup align ="right">
            <p:button value="Pesquisar" outcome="/usuario/PesquisaUsuario"/>
        </p:toolbarGroup>
    </p:toolbar>

    <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="painel" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 20px" 
    columnClasses="rotulo, campo">

        <p:outputLabel value="Nome" for="nome"/>
        <p:inputText id="nome" size="60" maxlength="60"
        value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.usuario.nome}" required="true" requiredMessage="Informe seu nome" validatorMessage="formato de nome inválido">
        <f:validateRegex pattern="^[A-Za-záàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñÁÀÂÃÉÈÍÏÓÔÕÖÚÇÑ ]+$"/>
        </p:inputText>

        <p:outputLabel value="Senha" for="senha"/>
        <p:password id="senha" size ="10" maxlength="6" required="true" requiredMessage="Informe uma senha" value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.usuario.senha}" match="senha2" validatorMessage="As senhas informadas não coincidem. Informe-as novamente"/>

        <p:outputLabel value="Verifique sua senha" for="senha"/>
        <p:password id="senha2" size ="10" maxlength="6" required="true" requiredMessage="Confirme sua senha" value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.usuario.senha}" match="senha2"/>

        <p:outputLabel value="RG" for="rg"/>
        <p:inputText id="rg" size="20" maxlength="20"
            value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.usuario.rg}" required="true" requiredMessage="Informe o número do seu RG"/>

        <p:outputLabel value="CPF" for="cpf"/>
        <p:inputMask id="cpf" size="14" maxlength="14"
            value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.usuario.cpf}" mask="999.999.999-99" required="true" requiredMessage="Informe seu CPF"/>

        <p:outputLabel value="Email" for="email"/>
        <p:inputText id="email" size="50" maxlength="50"
            value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.usuario.email}" required="true" requiredMessage="Informe um email para contato" validatorMessage="formato de email inválido">

        <f:validateRegex
            pattern="^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$" />
        </p:inputText>

        <p:outputLabel value="Telefone para contato" for="telefone"/>
        <p:inputMask id="telefone" size="14" maxlength="14"
            value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.usuario.telefone}" mask="(99)9999-9999" required="true" requiredMessage="Informe um telefone para contato"/>

        <p:outputLabel value="Celular para contato" for="celular"/>
        <p:inputMask id="celular" size="14" maxlength="14"
            value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.usuario.celular}" mask="(99)999999999" required="true" requiredMessage="Informe um celular para contato"/>

        <p:outputLabel value="Estado" for="estado"/>
        <p:selectOneMenu id="estado" value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.estado}" label="Estado" filter="true" 
        filterMatchMode="contains" required="true" requiredMessage="Informe o estado de residência">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="" noSelectionOption = "true"/>
            <f:selectItems 
                value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.listEstados}" var="estado"
                itemValue="#{estado}"  itemLabel="#{estado.estado_sigla}" />
            <p:ajax listener="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.carregarCidades}" update="cidade"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>

        <p:outputLabel value="Cidade" for="cidade"/>
        <p:selectOneMenu id="cidade" value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.usuario.cidade}" required="true" requiredMessage="Informe a cidade de residência">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel=""/>
            <f:selectItems value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.listCidades}" var ="cidade"
            itemValue="#{cidade}" itemLabel="#{cidade.cidadeNome}"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>

        <p:outputLabel value="CEP" for="cep"/>
        <p:inputMask id="cep" size="8" maxlength="8"
            value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.usuario.cep}" mask="99999-999" required="true" requiredMessage="Informe o CEP de seu endereço"/>

        <p:outputLabel value="Endereço" for="endereco"/>
        <p:inputText id="endereco" size="100" maxlength="100"
            value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.usuario.endereco}" required="true" requiredMessage="Informe um endereço de correspondência"/>
    </p:panelGrid>



</h:form>
</ui:define>
```

**Usuario.java**

```
package com.sisRastrbov.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name ="usuario_sequence", sequenceName = "usuario_sequence")
@Table(name = "usuario")
public class Usuario implements Serializable{


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Long id;
private String nome;
private String senha;
private String status;
private String cpf;
private String rg;
private String email;
private String telefone;
private String celular;
private String endereco;
private Estado estado;
private Cidade cidade;
private String cep;
private List<Grupo> grupos = new ArrayList<>();

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "usuario_sequence")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false, length = 60)
public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false, length = 6)
public String getSenha() {
    return senha;
}

public void setSenha(String senha) {
    this.senha = senha;
}

@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false, length = 14, unique=true)
public String getCpf(){
    return cpf;
}

public void setCpf(String cpf){
    this.cpf = cpf;
}

@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false, length = 20)
public String getRg(){
    return rg;
}

public void setRg(String rg){
    this.rg = rg;
}

@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
public String getEmail(){
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email){
    this.email = email;
}

@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false, length = 14)
public String getTelefone(){
    return telefone;
}

public void setTelefone(String telefone){
    this.telefone = telefone;
}

@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false, length = 14)
public String getCelular() {
    return celular;
}

public void setCelular(String celular) {
    this.celular = celular;
}

@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false, length = 200)
public String getEndereco(){
    return endereco;
}

public void setEndereco(String endereco){
    this.endereco = endereco;
}

@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false, length = 9)
public String getCep(){
    return cep;
}

public void setCep(String cep){
    this.cep = cep;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "estado_sigla")
public Estado getEstado(){
    return estado;
}

public void setEstado(Estado estado){
    this.estado = estado;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "cidadeNome")
public Cidade getCidade() {
    return cidade;
}

public void setCidade(Cidade cidade) {
    this.cidade = cidade;
}

@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false, length = 7)
public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Usuario other = (Usuario) obj;
    if (id == null) {
        if (other.id != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
        return false;
    return true;
}

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "usuario_grupo", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="usuario_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "grupo_id"))
public List<Grupo> getGrupos() {
    return grupos;
}

public void setGrupos(List<Grupo> grupos) {
    this.grupos = grupos;
}

}
```

**UsuarioRep.java**

```
package com.sisRastrbov.repository;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.NoResultException;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Order;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;

import com.sisRastrbov.model.Usuario;
import com.sisRastrbov.repository.filter.UsuarioFilter;
import com.sisRastrbov.util.jsf.FacesUtil;

public class UsuariosRep implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Inject
private EntityManager manager;

public Usuario guardar(Usuario usuario) {
    EntityTransaction trx = manager.getTransaction();

    trx.begin();

    usuario = manager.merge(usuario);

    trx.commit();

    return usuario;
}

/*public Usuario porNome(String nome) 
{
    return manager.find(Usuario.class, nome);
}*/

public Usuario porNome(String nome) {
    Usuario usuario = null;

    try{
    usuario = this.manager.createQuery("from Usuario where lower(nome) = :nome", Usuario.class)
            .setParameter("nome", nome.toLowerCase()).getSingleResult();
    }catch (NoResultException e){
        // Nenhum usuario encontrado com o nome informado.
    }
    return usuario;
}

public Usuario porId(Long id)
{
    return manager.find(Usuario.class, id);
}

public List<Usuario> listaDeUsu() 
{
    return manager.createQuery("from Usuario", Usuario.class).getResultList();
}

public List<Usuario> raizes()
{
    return  manager.createQuery("from Usuario",Usuario.class).getResultList(); 
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Usuario> filtrados(UsuarioFilter filtro) {

    Session session = manager.unwrap(Session.class);

    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Usuario.class);

    if (filtro.getNome() != "") 
    {
        System.out.println(filtro.getNome());
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("nome", filtro.getNome()));
    }

    if (filtro.getStatus() != null)
    {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("status", filtro.getStatus()));
    }

    // orderBy do SQL
    return criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("id")).list();
}

public void remover(Usuario usuario) {
    this.manager.remove(usuario);
    EntityTransaction trx = manager.getTransaction();
    trx.begin();
    manager.flush();
    trx.commit();
}

public Usuario porEmail(String email) {
    Usuario usuario = null;

    try{
        usuario = this.manager.createQuery("from Usuario where lower(email) = :email", Usuario.class)
                .setParameter("email", email.toLowerCase()).getSingleResult();
    }
    catch (NoResultException e){
        FacesUtil.addErrorMessage("Nenhum usuário encontrado");
    }
    return usuario;
}
}
```

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org    /xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<context-param>  
<param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>  
<param-value>bootstrap</param-value>  
</context-param>
```

org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    
    
        org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher

```
<listener>
   <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
</listener>
<resource-env-ref>
   <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
   <resource-env-ref-type>
      javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager
   </resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Main.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

 <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Me desculpem pelo Web.xml ter ficado meio estranho, mas não consegui arrumar.
Acredito que o método guardar do UsuarioRep.java seria a chave para a solução.
Caso esteja faltando algum arquivo, por favor me avisem que adicionarei imediatamente.

Desde já agradeço qualquer opinião ou sugestão.

Comment: Por que você não cria  na tabela de cadastro uma chave primaria com o CPF e um index único com o e-mail e trata o erro dentro do programa?

Comment: Reginaldo Rigo, me desculpe mas não entendi exatamente o que você quis dizer com "index único".

Comment: Unique index não permitem registros duplicados nos campos que participam do indíce. Digite `create unique index` no Google e você poderá se informar melhor sobre isso.

Comment: @postgisBeginner, gostaria de adiciona um adendo sobre ArrayList: [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195006/6789). Por registro duplicados, e o uso da interface List e ArrayList tem relação com a resposta. Acredito que possa ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Experimente criar uma constraint no banco

Abaixo um exemplo com CNPJ no PostGres

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS empresa (
    id  bigserial not null,
    cnpj varchar(14) not null,
    razao_social varchar(30) not null,        
    email varchar(300) not null,         
    telefone varchar(14),
    cep varchar(8) not null,
    endereco varchar(100) not null,
    numero varchar(5),
    complemento varchar(100),
    cidade varchar(100) not null,
    bairro varchar(100) not null,
    uf varchar(2) not null,
    latitude numeric(19,15),
    longitude numeric(19,15),
    primary key (id)

)  ;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS empresa                                                   
    add constraint UK_cnpj unique (cnpj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Se você quiser exibir uma mensagem amigável para o usuário basta apenas tratar a exceção de banco lançada quando se tenta cadastrar um dado que quebra uma constraint unique. Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
public Usuario guardar(Usuario usuario) {
  EntityTransaction trx = manager.getTransaction();

  trx.begin();

  try {
    usuario = manager.merge(usuario);
  } catch (Exception e) {
     throw new MinhaExcecaoDeNegocio(e.getMessage());
  }

  trx.commit();

  return usuario;
}
```

Com o catch capturando a exceção você pode lançar uma exceção de negócio checável (MinhaExcecaoDeNegocio deve ser implementada extendendo Exception) e capturá-la no seu cadastroUsuarioBean, que irá adicionar a mensagem para o usuário no facesContext. Eu coloquei como exemplo o catch de Exception mas você poderia colocar uma exceção mais específica no catch, o que é recomendado inclusive.
Espero ter ajudado ^^